# Creating overlays and calculating area of intersect

Tags: arcgis-pro, csv, raster-calculator, zonal-statistics, overlay

I'm currently mapping for deforestation and species risk from palm oil plantations. I'm trying to calculate the area of intersect between the individual species and p-oil plantations and deforestation and P-oil (individually). After I have calculated this, I want to use a CSV file containing the ID for each province, to match the trade data contained in the CSV with the species and deforestation risk scores of each province (area of intersect). The area of risk for each province will then be divided by the total production of palm oil (tonnes) for the province, to gather a risk intensity score – which will then be multiplied by the total volume of trade in palm oil for the country.

I have my Species, P-oil and deforestation maps as raster layers (as well as a raster layer with the provinces), and I know that I need to create overlays with raster calculator and then use zonal statistics to complete the calculations however I'm struggling to distinguish which layers are required in the overlay and then my next steps from then onwards - Especially how to include the CSV file in the calculations. I'm assuming I just need palm oil and my species range/deforestation in the overlay rather than the province map - which will be needed with the zonal statistics. I'm Using ArcGIS Pro & haven't been using the python window as yet, but rather working from the toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [Combine](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/combine.htm) tool of the Spatial Analysis toolbox for this purpose.

Assuming all your rasters integer/categorical (or can be converted to integer by using some threshold values), you can "combine" your rasters and each cell with any raster value will show the underlying raster combination. Then you can add extra string fields to the combine's result raster to calculate human-readable look up values (say value of 1 represents orangutans in your species layer and you can calculate "Orangutan" against the value of 1 in the new field). This table can be exported to a CSV for further analysis as well. The Count column will give you the total number of cells associated with the specific combination, which you may need to convert this to a areal unit later on.

I am leaving the matters related to the extent, resolution and origin of your rasters to you to investigate, as well as the MAUP.